# Timeout between steps in selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

Is it possible to set some timeout between steps as in QTP we have global option "Delay each step execution by"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should instead use waitForElementPresent(). Selenium transforms this into a loop of Thread.sleep ultimately, but this is the best practice. The element being loaded depends on the test environment and as such is not coherent all the time. By using this method, you can forget about such worries

Answer (score 2):

I know the Java code, look for something similar in C#:

`Thread.sleep(1000);` where 1000 is 1 sec.

Comment: Yes, i know this but i must put this code after each step in my script. I wondered about some global option.

Comment: I'm afraid not. You could also use explicit waits. Or write your own WebDriver methods like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576120/webdriver-does-not-reliably-click-links-or-buttons